# Regular expression could not be compiled. Apache 2.4.18

Tags: regex, .htaccess

So our host has updated their servers to the latest version of apache, and has caused all sorts of errors on the site. The main one being the following within the apache error logs, causing a 500 error on the main website.

Regular expression could not be compiled.

```
RewriteRule ^video-management/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)$ manage-videos.php?bizID=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^video-management/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/delete/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)$ manage-videos.php?bizID=$1&delImg=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^_shared/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)$ _shared/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)$ plugins/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)$ admin/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)$ pages/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\+\.]+)$ images/$1/$2/$3 [NC,L]
```

I cannot understand how anything should have changed with an update to Apache, and looking over the regular expressions on the above, seems that I cannot see any errors which would cause this issue.

When I comment out the above lines, the website works again (well mostly).

Comment: You should specify your original version too, usually it's easy with such well known products to find a migration guide that depicts your exact problem.

Comment: @Aaron - I have looked all over for this type of error and it seems that not many people are getting this error. Baically our host updated Apache from what ever version it was on for years previously (not sure the old version), but now its on version 2.4.18 - After the update, I get the error "Regular expression could not be compiled" in the apache error logs and a 500 error of the website.

If i comment out the lines above, the site loads, but does not load properly due to the above rewrite rules being commented out.

Comment: I don't know, that all look good to me. You could remove the A-Z classes since you replace with the NoCase flag, but that wouldn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days bashing my head, I finally figured out that there was an error in the regular expression.

The correct result should be

```
 ([A-Za-z0-9_\-\s\+]+)
```

I missed a \ before the dash.

Comment: This was simple. Glad you found the solution

Comment: @Gislef Thanks - Too bad other people gave me bad rep and down voted my initial question

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand your question. But you can make a comparison of active modules in the earlier version of apache with the current version of Apache, maybe  some module is disabled and is not recognizing the .htaccess.

Check your httpd.conf file.

Another possibility is the path in .htaccess
try replacing:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /folderYourHosting/example.com/
```

Comment: Hi @Gislef, I have tried changing the RewriteBase to the path of the website without any success of getting the htaccess to work correctly again. As for the httpd.conf, that is something I cannot check on as we only have a certain section of the server.